# Is there a way to join more than two datasets at once?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have 4 datasets with different schemas.
I need to join them with `left-anti`. 
Instead of joining them one by one, I would like to know is there any way to join all of them at once.

Comment: yes, you can do that using nested join in datafarame.

Comment: @maheshgupta can you elaborate that? or point me towards something that does.

Comment: I will add sample example

Answer (score 1):

So here is the spark2.4.3 nested join. So I have just taken random stuff to give you an idea to implement nested join.

> First DataFrame

```
 scala>    val someDF = Seq(
("user1", "math","algebra-1","90"),
("user1", "physics","gravity","70"),
("user3", "biology","health","50"),
("user2", "biology","health","100"),
("user1", "math","algebra-1","40"),
("user2", "physics","gravity-2","20")
).toDF("user_id", "course_id","lesson_name","score")

scala> someDF.show
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|user_id|course_id|lesson_name|score|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   90|
|  user1|  physics|    gravity|   70|
|  user3|  biology|     health|   50|
|  user2|  biology|     health|  100|
|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   40|
|  user2|  physics|  gravity-2|   20|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
```

> Second DataFrame

```
scala> var someDF2 = Seq(("math",121),("physics",122),("biology",123)).toDF("sid","rno")
scala> someDF2.show
+-------+---+
|    sid|rno|
+-------+---+
|   math|121|
|physics|122|
|biology|123|
+-------+---+
```

> Third DataFrame

```
scala> var someDF3 = Seq((121,"G-1"),(122,"G-2"),(123,"G-3")).toDF("rno","grade")

scala> someDF3.show
+---+-----+
|rno|grade|
+---+-----+
|121|  G-1|
|122|  G-2|
|123|  G-3|
+---+-----+

scala> someDF.join(someDF2,col("course_id")===col("sid"),"inner").join(someDF3,Seq("rno"),"inner").show
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----+-------+-----+                         
|rno|user_id|course_id|lesson_name|score|    sid|grade|
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----+-------+-----+
|121|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   90|   math|  G-1|
|122|  user1|  physics|    gravity|   70|physics|  G-2|
|123|  user3|  biology|     health|   50|biology|  G-3|
|123|  user2|  biology|     health|  100|biology|  G-3|
|121|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   40|   math|  G-1|
|122|  user2|  physics|  gravity-2|   20|physics|  G-2|
+---+-------+---------+-----------+-----+-------+-----+
```

there is no meaning of any data however it will serve your purpose. let me know if you have any question related to the same.